# How to generate random master password?

Tags: password, encryption, random

I want to generate a secure random password for the encrypted Linux system. What offline tools should I use? Any advice if I should use `xkcdpass`, `apg`, `diceware`, or another utility, and how built should this password be?

I need a difficult-to-crack password for people who could access directly the laptop and try to force me to give them password.

Comment: We can't really help without more information. Unfortunately, the word "secure" is meaningless unless you explain the exact threat scenario you are thinking of. What is secure in one context won't be secure enough in another. Please [edit] your question and explain what kind of situation you need to deal with.  Oh, and also tell us what operating system you are using.

Comment: Is that edit good? I added a sentence.

Comment: Thanks, but it's more about what you want to protect yourself from. Is it your friend who is bored and would want to play a trick on you? Is it a foreign or local government agency with their resources? The two are very different situations and what is a "secure" password for one, will not be enough for the other. I mean, if you're just a regular person and don't want your passwords stolen, just use any tool at all. For anything more, you would need to define the threat you are considering. Obligatory XKCD reference: https://xkcd.com/538/

Comment: You cannot argue with a wrench.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Yes I know it but I tried to prepare for this scenario by loading a key file from the ramdisk encrypted on USB.

Comment: @terdon Is that question now better? I changed context from keepassxc db to the encrypted system on which I'll store the file.

Comment: You can install pwgen or pwmake and generate as long or as many passwords as you like offline. But remember that all passwords can be cracked. See for example https://tinyurl.com/2n9xcx4e

Comment: You absolutely have to use hidden containers: https://arcanecode.com/2021/05/31/creating-and-using-hidden-containers-in-veracrypt/ and two passwords. You can give out an outward password, but your inward data protected by an inward password will not be found.

Comment: Is there a reason why most password manager shouldn’t be able to generate a password that is secure enough for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `gpg` which most, if not all, distros ship pre-installed.
To do so, execute `gpg --gen-random --armor 1 <password length (integer)> | base64` in a terminal.

I.e. if you want a 24 char long password, you would do `gpg --gen-random --armor 1 24 | base64`.